# Integrating Google ML Kit for iOS without using pod/cocoapod

Tags: google-mlkit

How can integrate Google ML Kit for iOS(Objective C) without using pod/cocoapod? My App does not use cocoapod/pod or Swift Package Manager.

Thanks

Hi All,

How can integrate Google ML Kit for iOS(Objective C) without using pod/cocoapod?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The ML Kit library is only provided as cocoapods.

From https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios

The "Before You Begin" section of the following page mentions CocoaPods as the only option:

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/ios

> 1. Include the following ML Kit pods in your Podfile:

Although you may be running into problems with CocoaPods, it appears the only way forward is to resolve those problems.